# how when I am open dialogue how to hide the sub div if not required if required need to show

Tags: jquery, html

```
   how when I am open main div using open dialogue how to hide the sub div if not required
    if required need to show please kindly help out from this
my problem is when iam open main div all sub divs also opened
```

below my example is their
         how when I am open main div using open dialogue how to hide the sub div if not required
        if required need to show please kindly help out from this
    my problem is when iam open main div all sub divs also opened
below my example is their

```
    Example:<main div>
    <sub div1>hi</sub div1>
    <sub div2>hello</sub div2>
    <sub div3>hi</sub div3>
    </main div>

    open dialogue using jquery

     Open_Dialog1('#maindiv', true, true, true, false, 1150, 800, 'slideRight', 'slideLeft', 200, 200, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

give an id to each div and make their property in css as visibility:hidden;
then by java script make the changes to the css property on giving the condition
el.style.visibility = "visible";
e1 is id

Comment: Thank you for your answer and please give one example for the same

Comment: Thank u.  am using this $('#dvPrevSchdCJCWorkPermit').css('visibility', 'hidden'); this is hidden div but it displayed empty pages so how to display with out empty pages